# Using Code Contracts to ensure collection remains unchanged

Tags: c#, code-contracts, design-by-contract

I'm trying to implement the post-condition of a method. I want to guarantee that it doesn't change a particular part of the internal state (I fixed a bug, as it used to do so. For refression purposed, I'm adding the post-condition in code). My best attempt was as follows:

```
Contract.Ensures(PropertyA.Collection.Count == Contract.OldValue(PropertyA.Collection).Count);
Contract.Ensures(Contract.ForAll(0, PropertyA.Collection.Count, index => this.PropertyA.Collection[index].Equals(Contract.OldValue(this.PropertyA.Collection)[index])));
```

The problem with this code is that `Contract.OldValue(PropertyA.Collection)` caused a null reference exception in the second line. In the manual of Code Contracts in section 11.8 (http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/userdoc.pdf) is stated that this particular `Contract.ForAll` ought to work with `Contract.OldValue`, but another overload doesn't.

Is there another way how I can perform the check that the items in PropertyA.Collection haven't changed in value, nor have been reordered in some way?

Comment: I'd probably write a test instead of using pre-/postconditions to track that the regression doesn't, well, regress again. That way you'd still notice and you don't burden your callers with checking every single time.

Comment: @Јοеу: I've already written a test as well, so it's also covered there. The callers don't have any obligation to check for post conditions. The called method guarantees that PropertyA's Collection remains unaffected.

Comment: I meant the performance burden, not that the callers need to do something every time :-)

Comment: @Јοеу: Ah, well that might be a concern for the debug-version, but not for the release version. Code Contracts will not be compiled in the release version of the application. Fortunately, the method with this contract will only be executed at particular parts of the application once (not many times in a row), so the performance burden can be considered acceptable in our case. But I agree with you, that it's wise to take it into account.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear from your question, but I expect that `PropertyA.Collection` and `PropertyB.Collection` are reference types.
One gotcha with `Contracts.OldValue()` and reference types is, that `Contracts.OldValue()` doesn't save the old object pointed at, but rather the pointer itself.

For this reason, your first contract will always be true, since you effectively compare the value to itself.
The proper way to write it would be

```
Contract.Ensures(PropertyA.Collection.Count == Contract.OldValue(PropertyA.Collection.Count));
```

I'm not sure why your second contract fails.
Normally when trying to compare a collection before and after a method call, you need to save the collection as an enumerable:

```
Contract.OldValue(PropertyA.Collection.ToList())
// or
Contract.OldValue(PropertyA.Collection.ToArray())
```

This will evaluate the expression and save the reverence to the list/array, which can then be indexed.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to answer so late, but there are not too much activity in code contracts.

I think there are two sides of the problem:

1) To ensure the condition, as you ask, I think that can be done using a [Pure] function to do it, and calling this function in the Contract.Ensures

2) Unfortunately it only solves the problem locally. Note this situation:

1- Call a function which ensures a condition on de collection
 2- Call a function which ensures no change in the collection
 3- Call a function which has as precondition the condition ensured in (1)

The [Pure] function in (2) to ensure no change is done in the collection does not allow CodeContracts to infer that the postcondition in (1) ensures the precondition in (3).

I think that CodeContracts should offer a functionality to ensure no change in an object, but taking the object as the "deep object"; something that lets you write something like

*proposal code*
*Contract.Ensures(PureArgument(PropertyA.Collection))*

As the functionality *PureArgument* should be part of CodeContracts, it could be an attribute:

*proposal code*
*[PureArgument(PropertyA.Collection)]*

Note that CodeContracts could check that the *PureArgument* property is fulfilled, as it can do a deep compare; really complex and expensive to check (it needs a deep copy), but it can be done. But the checking won't be the question, but to check the code to ensure that the parameter is not deep changed, which is not always possible.

Anyway, I'm sure that a feature like that will be great, even without checking it fullfils the assertion, and without checking the code to ensure the parameter is not changed (which is more interesting than checking the assertion is fullfiled, but impossible to cover at all).

Turning back to the question, a solution to ensure that a collection doesn't change could be to use *new ReadOnlyCollection(PropertyA.Collection)* as parameter, instead of using PropertyA, but it is a change in the code.